# How does the mortal seeming of a Leanhaun sidhe age?

Tags: world-of-darkness, changeling-the-dreaming

House Leanhaun sidhes have a strange curse. If they don't perform a Rhapsody each month, they age a year each week. This means a childling could reach adulthood in few months.

Does this also affect the mortal seeming? If the noble is still living with his parents, how will they see that? Do the Mists make everybody rationalize the premature aging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not as though the sidhe's physical form will age accordingly — that is, unless the changeling Calls Upon the Wyrd or otherwise manifests their dream self in the real world. However, the child will begin to seem older and wiser in an eerie way. Imagine one of those movies where an adult swaps bodies with a child; that's the impression that they'll get. Or the child will seem more hardened and wizened, as though they've been through a trauma. Sunken eyes, less sleep, more aged without being actually older.